# How much money do you require for a 4-nights stay in Toronto? - It's a question on visitor visa application

Tags: visas, canada, applications

How much money do you require for a 4-nights stay in Toronto? - It's a question on visitor visa application. I just need to make visa officer happy, because I have to be neutral on amounts, sometime a big can be a problem as well.

We are planning a 4-nights sightseeing tour to Toronto, Canada and I have come across the above question on visa application form, so thought of asking you guys as **I don't want to put an amount lesser than standard expectation by the visa officers**. I surely have enough money on my bank, but **also don't want to put even a big amount and make him get a doubt/confuse on decision**.

Comment: How much are you actually planning to spend?  Why not put that amount on the application?

Comment: @phoog because I'm really frugal, to the point of sharing one Tim Horton donut between a family of 4, so my answer might be unusually low ;-)

Comment: @djna if you are feeding your family on a quarter of a donut each, then a country would probably be justified in refusing entry.

Comment: @phoog true :-)

Answer (score 6):

Plausible mid-range touristy sort of answer.

- Decent hotel: $125 a night
- Meals: $75 per day per person
- Fun (Museums, ferries, transport): $50 per day per person

So $250-$350 a day minimum

Clearly possible to cut the costs way down if you economise, cheap hostels etc. or spend loads more if you want better hotels, nice meals, shows etc.

Comment: I´d say 100 $ on budget level but if you don`t hold back djnas answer makes sense, especially for application purposes